# How to do foreach 1 until 100?

Tags: php, arrays

I need a simpler way like 1 - 100 instead of adding any number and number (1,2,3....)

```
$all_urls = array(1,2,3,4..,100);
foreach ($all_urls as $url){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/$url");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

> Create an array containing a range of elements
>
> ```
> // array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)           
> foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) {    
>     echo $number;      
> }
> ```

```
$all_urls = range(1,100);
```